# getting error Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: haskell

[image: sample input/output]

I am very new in haskell, i wrote the code for item details and search the detail for each item.

```
type Code = Int
type Name = String 
type Database = (Code,Name)

textfile::IO()
textfile = appendFile "base.txt" (show[(110,"B")])
```

code for search

```
fun::IO ()
fun=do putStrLn"Please enter the code of the product"
       x<-getLine
       let y = read x :: Int
       show1 y 

textshow::IO [Database]
textshow= do x<-readFile "base.txt"
             let y=read x::[Database]
         return y

show1::Code->IO ()
show1 cd= do o<-textshow
             let d=[(x,y)|(x,y)<-o,cd==x]
         putStr(show d)
```

but, the problem is, it is working good for single data, if i append another data, then it showing error `Prelude.read: no parse` when i am trying to search the item.
Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Can you please add a sample input that triggers the problem?

Comment: i have uploaded sample i/o snap , please have a look on.

Comment: There's also indentation issues in textshow and show1.  But I think this shows the problem.  Answering shortly.

Comment: @ibid thanks for your answer, i got the mistake,but i am very new in haskell, can you please... explain through the ocde. i'll appreciate !!

Comment: I've updated the answer.  It's a bit tricky, I grant you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in the format of your data file.  After one use of `textfile`, the file contains the following:

```
[(110,"B")]
```

That's a good list, and it works.  After the second use of `textfile`, the file contains the following:

```
[(110,"B")][(110,"B")]
```

That's not a good list, and it fails.  You can see this in `ghci`:

```
*Main> read "[(110,\"B\")][(110,\"B\")]" :: [Database]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

It's clear that `read` expects a single list, not two lists following each other.

If you want to append to a file that contains a single Haskell list, you need to read the file, append to the list, and write the new list in the file as a replacement.

```
addToFileList :: (Read a, Show a) => FilePath -> a -> IO ()
addToFileList fp a = do olds <- readFile fp `catch` \e ->
                                if isDoesNotExistError e 
                                then return "[]"
                                else ioError e
                        let oldl = read olds
                            newl = oldl ++ [a]
                            news = show newl
                        length news `seq`
                               writeFile fp news
```

This is a little tricky because  of two tings:

- `readFile` is lazy, and `writeFile` to the same file can fail unless one makes sure that the whole file has already been read.  In the function above this is solved by asking for the length of the new string before writing the file (the `seq` function makes sure that the length is computed before the write operation happens).
- the file may not exist, the `catch` clause is used above to handle that exceptional case.